# How to create an VS application page that does not inherit the master page?

Tags: master-page, application-pages

We are creating an application page and do not want it to inherit the masterpage. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove master page reference from your site

Comment: What do you mean "Remove master page reference from your site first". Do you mean by going to Site Settings -->Site Master Page Settings? there you can choose different master pages. you cannot remove it.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a line similar like this in your .aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CreateCollabWeb.aspx.cs" Inherits="Something.Layouts.CreateCollabWeb" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>
```

Here you can point to a different master page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CreateCollabWeb.aspx.cs" Inherits="Something.Layouts.CreateCollabWeb" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/myCustomMaster.master" %
```

Comment: OK, what if I want it to be an empty page with white background and text. No masterpage at all.

Comment: Then you would have to have a "blank" masterpage. You can also call your page with `?isDlg=1` to get rid of leftnav and parts of the header

Comment: Is there any option, this is for purpose of creating a terms and conditions page. Any other idea?

Comment: Those are your options

Answer (score 2):

Remember that Application pages are just normal `.aspx` pages, nothing SharePoint specific.

So you can just remove the `DynamicMasterPageFile` property from the `<%@ Page %>` tag.

Just remember to add `html`, `head`, `body` now that a masterpage is no longer dictating the html structure.

Comment: But I want to use the sharepoint object model in the code behind.

Comment: page gives error

Comment: I tried this but there is technical error when loading page

Comment: @variable What does the ULS log say?

Comment: I guess it needed somthing with runat=server; <form runat="server"> worked